# gulp 3.9.1 gulp watch не работает

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch

Выдает ошибку, стоит gulp 3.9.1, gulp-cli 2.2.0 node 12.16.2, npm 6.14.4,

```
D:\www\projects\project>gulp watch
fs.js:35
} = primordials;
    ^

ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
←[90m    at fs.js:35:5←[39m
    at req_ (D:\www\projects\project\node_modules\←[4mnatives←[24m\index.js:143:
24)
    at Object.req [as require] (D:\www\projects\project\node_modules\←[4mnatives
←[24m\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\www\projects\project\node_modules\←[4mvinyl-fs←[24
m\node_modules\←[4mgraceful-fs←[24m\fs.js:1:37)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:1
0)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)←[39m
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp 3 не поддерживается Node.js 12.16.2

Решение: установить более раннюю версию Node.js (например, 11.15) либо переходить на Gulp 4.

Comment: спасибо, сработало)

Comment: Рад был помочь, отметьте мой ответ решением

Comment: отметил но "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Comment: @Skyline73731 Вам нужно нажать на галочку под рейтингом, так вы отметите ответ решением. Кроме вас никто этого сделать не сможет.

Comment: Для того, чтобы отметить ответ принятым, нажмите на серую галку рядом с ответом. Галка станет зелёной. Это будет означать, что ответ отмечен как решение вопроса. Вы можете в любой момент снять галку или отметить ею другой ответ.

Comment: Я пробовал несколько ра, сначало поднимаеться на едеиницу потом выдает ответ который написал выше